# kubernetes rolling updates not creating new pods

Tags: kubernetes

Below is my deployment file. I am trying to bring up new pod and bring down old pod using rolling update of kubernetes. I get a success message as

```
deployment "gql-deployment" successfully rolled out but pod remains as it is.


---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: gql-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: gql-pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: gql-cont
        image: bitnami/nginx:1.14
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 512Mi
            cpu: 500m        
          limits:
            memory: 512Mi
            cpu: 500m
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 80
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 5
          successThreshold: 1
```

step1:

```
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
```

Step2: I change the image name to

```
bitnami/nginx:1.14.2
```

Step3:

```
kubectl rollout status deployment.v1beta1.extensions/gql-deployment
```

I get message like `deployment "gql-deployment" successfully rolled out`

But pod names remains same. Am i missing some step?

Comment: What commands/steps are you using to update the image name? Can you provide the return of `kubectl rollout history deployment/gql-deployment`?

Comment: @EduardoBaitello - In Step2, i update the deployment.yaml file manually. Is this the right way ti change image? Below is what i get using history command.


REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
1         <none>

Comment: you need to `kubectl apply -f` the file again after changing it. Kubernetes doesn't watch the manifest files used to create the resources, you need to tell it for the apiserver every time.

Comment: @EduardoBaitello - But if i apply, it would go for direct deployment right? When do i run rollout command?

Comment: Hacker, there is no need to run an explicit rollout command. The configured `strategy` for your deployment is `RollingUpdate`, so any changes on `.spec.template` (this includes containers images) will trigger a rollout automatically.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment) doc. Changing the file and `kubectl apply` it is, in pratice, the same of `kubectl edit` the deployment as stated  in the docs. Both will trigger Rolling Update deployments if you change container images.

Comment: @EduardoBaitello - If i change image name and do kubectl apply, it starts a new pod and old pod is never klilled.

Answer (score 0):

For Step 2 you should do

```
kubectl set image deployment.v1.apps/gql-deployment gql-cont=nginx:1.14.2 --record=true
```

As you can see on the screenshot below old pod is terminated and new one with image **1.14.2** has been started

A rollout history also shows a successful update

[image]

Comment: Even if i remove rolling updates, it works same. So why do i need to add rolling updates?

Comment: @Hacker it looks like your pod is not ready. Are you sure your readinessProbe did not fail?  Can you please update your post with pod description?  `kubectl describe pod  <pod-name>`

Answer (score -2):

Deployment is working properly with "nginx" images. I would suggest to test "readinessProbe" with different images. Hope this help.

Comment: It failed with my regular image, so tried testing with nginx. Am i missing any step?

Comment: You can apply your deployment as described above: kubectl apply -f your_deployment.yaml

It would be great to have more details:

`kubectl get pods,deploy,rs`
`kubectl describe pod your_pod` (please take a look also for: Limits:"Cpu and Memory", Image, events, Readiness.
In addition: 
`kubectl rollout status your_deployment` 
`kubectl rollout history your_deployment `
`kubectl logs pod your_pod`